Unable to add a column named 'Investor Type'
I have a dataframe which has 500 rows * 454 columns. I want to add a column that says 'Investor Type' after every column that says 'Description'.
So the data frame column labels look like this:
Annual Report Name, Annual Report Year, Annual Report, Outstanding shares, Shareholder Name, Shares Owned, Description, Shareholder Name, Shares Owned, Description..........................Shareholder Name, Shares Owned, Description

The first 'Description' label is at column index 6 (assuming 0 indexing). Thereafter, 'Description' repeats every three columns. I want to insert 'Investor Type' after every 'Description' column, so at column index 7, column index 11, and so on until the last column of the dataframe.
I have tried this below:
for col in df_expanded.columns:
    if col == 'Description':
        idx = df_expanded.columns.get_loc(col)
        df_expanded.insert(idx + 1, 'Shareholder Type', None, allow_duplicates = True)

This results in an error saying loc must be int.
What I would like as output is:
Annual Report Name, Annual Report Year, Annual Report, Outstanding shares, Shareholder Name, Shares Owned, Description, Shareholder Type, Shareholder Name, Shares Owned, Description, Shareholder Type..........................Shareholder Name, Shares Owned, Description, Shareholder Type

I am unsure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

idx = df_expanded.columns.get_loc(col) will always return the index of the first Description column, not the current one.

@Barmar it is not correct, btw
get_col it such cases return slice (if columns are near) or boolean index, marking positions of all requested cols
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html

I was also not correct about slices: get_loc returns slice object not just when "columns are near", but when all index is monotonic (i.e. all columns are ordered alphabetically). But in this example it's not a case.

You need to loop over the column indexes, not the columns, so you can distinguish columns with the same name.
You should also iterate in reverse order, because when you insert a column the indexes of later columns change.
for i in range(len(df_expanded.columns), -1, -1):
    if df_expanded.columns[i] == 'Description':
        df_expanded.insert(i + 1, 'Shareholder Type', None, allow_duplicates = True)


df_expanded.columns.get_loc(col) will return you an index [False, False, ..., True, ...] where True represents position of columns you find.
This code can help:
for idx in np.flatnonzero(df_expanded.columns.get_loc('Description'))[::-1]:
    # flatnonzero returns indexes of True in the list
    # and we iterate them backwards because positions 
    # in the right end of dataframe will move right
    # after new columns are inserted
    df_expanded.insert(idx + 1, 'Shareholder Type', None, allow_duplicates=True)

